# Finding the potential energy of a geosynchronous satellite above earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, satellites

I am trying to find the gravitational potential energy of a 1kg geostationary satellite above the earth. So far:

$E=mgh$, and $g=GM/r^2$ so substitution of $g$ into the energy equation gives:
$E=GMmh/r^2$.

Substituting $G$ and $M$ for their respective values, $m=1$, $h=35700000$ m, $r=42000000$ m
Gives me a value for the energy of 8MJ.

I have no idea if this is correct. This is method I have come up with just now and I'm not sure if it's a valid way to calculate the potential energy. Am I right, or is the situation more complicated?

Comment: What are the units for $h$ and $r$? And why aren't the two values equal?

Comment: Metres. I figured h is the height gained - the 35700km above the surface for a geostationary orbit. r is the distance of the satellite from the centre of mass of the earth, which is 35700 + Earth radius = 42000km

Answer (score 1):

The formula $mgh$ only works close to the Earth's surface where $g$ can be assumed constant. That is not the case here.

The appropriate formula is more like 
$$ E = m \int g(r)\ dr $$
where $g(r)$ is gravity as a function of radius from the centre of the Earth. This is the work done in moving the mass $m$ in the gravitational field. *If* $g$ were constant and the difference between the upper and lower limits was $h$ then you can see this reduces to $mgh$.

Which brings me to the second point. You need to think about where the zeropoint of potential energy is or in other words, how to put limits onto the integral above.

You can define it as the difference in potential between the Earth's surface and the geosynchronous radius, multiplied by the mass in question, but it is more usual to think of it with respect to a zeropoint (i.e. the lower limit in the integral) at infinity and hence the GPE of an object is actually negative (because you would gain KE bringing it to that point from some large distance).

Sorry I'm not giving an answer but this is clearly a homework type question; but I wanted to clear up the conceptual error.